# If G is not commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Edit: Since I did not provide enough detail in my explanation in OP: I have tried to prove this for the general case, but have not come across a suitable proof. I was unsure if I then needed to prove this generally, of if an example was sufficient. If there is a general proof for this, it would be appreciated.

Let $G$ be a group and let $o(a)=2, o(b)=3$, for some $a,b \in G$. Show that, if $G$ is not commutative, then $o(ab)$ is not necessarily $6$.

Comment: What do you know about non-abelian groups? What have you tried?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: @phatty in order for us to answer your question in a way that will be useful and informative, it helps if you give us some idea of what you've tried. As you've stated the question, it looks as if you've just copied it from a homework assignment - people tend not to appreciate that. Please could you edit your question to indicate what you've tried, or your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\;S_3\;$ , take $\;a=(12)\;,\;\;b=(123)\;$ . We don't even need to check what the product is to know it can't have order six.